# Data in a variable address doesn't update when I change the value

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

I try to send some data over the network. Two long value in addition to a character. I convert data to the byte form using the `memcpy` function in the `results` variable and send them over the network using a UDP connection:

```
#define SERVER "127.0.0.1"
#define PORT 9090

void die(char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}

using namespace std ;

int main() {

    char* results = new char[17];
    nanoseconds ns = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
    long a = ns.count() ;
    long b = 1l ;
    char end = '\n';
    memcpy(results, &a, 8);
    memcpy(results + 8, &b, 8);
    memcpy(results + 16, &end, 1);

    struct sockaddr_in si_other;
    int sock ,slen=sizeof(si_other);
    if ( (sock=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
    {
        die("socket");
    }

    memset((char *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
    si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_other.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if (inet_aton(SERVER , &si_other.sin_addr) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "inet_aton() failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    cout << "Sending data over the network ..." << endl;
    while (true) {
        ns = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
        a = ns.count() ;
        b += 1 ;
        // cout << a << endl ;
        memcpy(results, &a, 8);
        memcpy(results + 8, &b, 8);
        // cout << *((unsigned long*)results) << endl ;
        // memcpy(results + 16, &end, 1);

        if (sendto(sock, results, 17 , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen)==-1)
            {
               die("sendto()");
            }
    }
}
```

I checked data in the destination and it's all the same with the value that has been set to variables before the `while` loop. The data in the `results` variable is updating, too, but what is sending over the network is all constant!

I guess it's because of the `sendto` function behavior. Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm assuming the magic number 8 is supposed to be `sizeof(long)` on your platform?

Comment: can you keep your code DRY? Do not write everything in one big function. It is hard to read.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes, it is.

Comment: how fast your program executes. Maybe this `while` loop is faster than resolution of `high_resolution_clock`?

Comment: @SoheilPourbafrani Then I would *strongly* recommend using `sizeof(long)`. The size of `long` is not always 8. While we're at it, you should use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::rep` instead of `long`, or just `auto`.

Comment: Or maybe receiver code is faulty. Did you check WireShark to see what actually was sent?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux they should use neither `whatever_clock::rep` nor `auto` (nor indeed `long`) as the data is sent over a socket and the size should be known across all systems. Simplest solution would be to use `std::int64_t` (although, that is not necessarily ideal either, since it is not guaranteed to be available on all systems).

Comment: @MarekR If it was because of the `high_resolution_clock`, after a while the data should be updated anyway but it's constant for a long time! Am I right?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You're right, I'll change it to `sizeof(long)`.